# Container with mixed types vs. single choice principle

Tags: c++, oop

I am pondering over my design of a picking mechanism for a 3D tool. In the tool, there are several pickable objects with different capabilities, meaning I have to differentiate between them for the UI (show different palettes etc. based on whatever the user has picked).

The picking mechanism is basically a container that knows all the objects in the document and can answer queries for the objects which are hit by a pick ray. It returns a list of hits, sorted by their distance to the camera. To register an object with the picker, it must implement the `Pickable` interface:

```
class Pickable {
    typedef enum {
        Entity,
        Brush,
        Patch
    } Type;

    virtual Type getType() const = 0;

    virtual const BBox3& getBounds() const = 0;

    // Returns the distance of the intersection point with the given ray
    // or NaN if this object doesn't intersect with the given ray.
    virtual double intersects(const Ray3& ray) const = 0;
};
```

The picker internally stores all objects in a spatial data structure (an octree) which of course only knows them as instances of `Pickable`. All the objects being hit by the pick ray are then wrapped in instances of `Hit`:

```
class Hit {
    double getDistance() const;
    const Vec3& getHitPoint() const;
    Pickable* getObject() const;
};
```

which are then added to a vector and sorted by distance. Now if I want to do something with the hit objects, I have to do something along the lines of

```
Hit hit = ... // obtain a hit from the picker
Pickable* object = hit.getObject();
switch (object->getType()) {
    case Pickable::Entity:
        // cast to Entity and perform some operation
        break;
    case Pickable::Brush:
        // cast to Brush and perform some operation
       break;
    ...
}
```

This of course violates the [single choice principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleChoicePrinciple). If I ever add a new object type, I have to touch all those switch statements which are strewn all over my codebase. For some operations that I want to apply to these objects, I can use a common super interface such as

```
class Object {
    virtual void transform(const Mat4x4& transformation);
    // other operations which are applicable to any type of object

    // I could even move some UI related functions into this interface:
    Palette* getUIPalette() const;
    void populateUIPalette(Palette* palette) const;
};
```

But there are some operations which can only be applied to entities, and some which can only be applied to brushes, and so on. The only solution I see is to move all operations into the `Object` interface, providing empty default implementations for operations which do not apply to all object types. But this also feels wrong as this would inflate the `Object` interface considerably.

My question is, are these the only two options or am I missing something? I really want to avoid casting and type checking as much as possible, but in this case, I don't see a good way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

Something like:

```
class IPickableVisitor;

class Pickable {
public:

    virtual void accept(IPickableVisitor& t);
};

class Entity : public Pickable {
public:
    void accept(IPickableVisitor& t) override { t.visit(*this); }
};

class Brush : public Pickable {
public:
    void accept(IPickableVisitor& t) override { t.visit(*this); }
};

class IPickableVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Entity& entity) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Brush& brush) = 0;
};
```

Now you may write:

```
class HitPickableVisitor : public IPickableVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Entity& entity) override
    {
        // Do the entity hit code.
    }
    virtual void visit(Brush& brush) override
    {
        // Do the brush hit code.
    }
};
```

And latter:

```
Pickable* object = hit.getObject();
HitPickableVisitor hitPickableVisitor;
object->accept(hitPickableVisitor);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting idea. It removes the casts and the compiler will complain when I add a new object type and don't adapt all visitors by adding the appropriate visit methods. I'll have to think about how this relates to the single choice principle though ;-)

Comment: I think there is no better way to avoid the casts when retrieving objects from the mixed containers, so I'm marking this as the answer. Thanks again!